# Drupal views_get_view in custom service

Tags: views, services

I created a custom service with mymodule_services_resources and I'm calling a function to return some items. This function inside is calling a view with views_get_view. The problem is always return an empty array.

If tested the same code somewhere else it shows the right results, but it does not work with services. I have something like this:

```
$view = views_get_view('the_view');
$view->set_display('default');
$args = array("my_param");
$view->set_arguments($args);
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();   
$view->result; //empty array in the WS
```

I tried loading the admin user ($user = user_load(1); ) before calling the view but I had the same results.

Is there something I should add, change or remove in order I can get the results of a view calling service endpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `views_get_view_results('the_view', 'default', 'my_param');` instead, or use the Views datasource's sub module called Views JSON.

Answer (score 0):

the module [services_views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) will help you expose the view as a resource in two different ways

It has currently two features:

- Create view based resource creating Services display in a view
- Execute any view of the system via views resource call